# Setting custom attribute in onbeforeunload() function does not work

Tags: javascript, session, newrelic

While trying to find the time spent for a user on a page, using onbeforeunload() function where i can record the current time and pass it as custom attribute to newrelic event. Tried below with no result.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {       
    doSomething();
    //event.returnValue = "Is this working";
    };

    function doSomething(){
            //const t = new Date();
            //const ctime = t.getTime();
            //Test
            newrelic.setCustomAttribute('ctime', "sal");
            }
```

No data being captured in newrelic event.

[image: O/p]

Comment: Any errors ? Are you sure that `newrelic` is loaded ?

Comment: No error, but the way newrelic works is that the custom attributes stores the value and can be queried. I am not getting any value for ctime variable. Attaching screenshot.

Comment: `newrelic` is a javascript ? I think the JS might not be loaded before windiw.onbeforeload. Try `DOMContentLoaded` event.